react-i18next and i18next-http-backend - how to do a single REST API call and fetch the namespaces from that response
I current have the following setup. But here the API call goes for each namespace. Is there a way to fetch all namespaces from a single API and use the same in response? GET -http://localhost:3015/resources gives all the namespaces in single API call
i18nservice.ts
import i18next from "i18next";
import I18NextHttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

const loadResources = async (language, namespace) => {
  return await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3015/resources/${namespace}`,
      {
        params: { language: language },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

const backendOptions = {
  loadPath: `{{lng}}/{{ns}}`,
  allowMultiLoading: false,
  crossDomain: false,
  request: (options, url, payload, callback) => {
    try {
      const [lng, ns] = url.split("/");
      loadResources(lng, ns).then((data) => {
        callback(null, {
          data: data,
          status: 200,
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      callback(null, {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  },
};
i18next
  .use(I18NextHttpBackend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    backend: backendOptions,
    lng: "en",
    partialBundledLanguages: true,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    preload: ["en"],
    ns: ["translation"],
    defaultNS: "translation",
    debug: false,
  });

export default i18next;


App.tsx
import i18n from "../i18nservice";
const App = () => {
    return 
    <>
          <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
                ... My component structure
          </I18nextProvider>
    </>
}

Read documentation tried ChatGPT. Could not find anything that helps in documentation and ChatGPT code sucks!
